# Infared & Thermal imaging

Tags: meteorology

Let's say I have an infared picture of the earth from the space station, is it possible to measure the temperature of the picture area, and thus convert the infared picture I have to a thermal picture?

Comment: I suggest you rephrase your question as "is it possible to calculate the temperature from infrared satellite data?"

Comment: Note that "infrared" can mean a lot of things. Especially relevant for your question is the distinction between far (longwave/thermal) IR and near (shortwave, near the visual range)

Comment: @tasos - https://discnrt1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/data/Aqua_NRT/AIRIBRAD_NRT.005/2017/300/AIRS.2017.10.27.001.L1B.AIRS_Rad.v5.0.23.0.R17299205301.hdf.jpg NASA already does this

Answer (score 1):

Temperature images are calculated from microwave and infrared data. So in principle yes.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite_temperature_measurements?wprov=sfla1